# Motion Deblur using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I learnt about `deconvlucy` and `deconvwnr` techniques to remove motion blur and they work pretty well on simulated deblurred images. Hence, I tried to check this algorithm on real footages captured with mobile. I also stabilised video using Movavi video editor.

And here is my code:

```
    I = imread('mobile_blur13.png');
    imshow(I);
    lengthmin = 12;
    lengthmax = 15;
    thetamin =331;
    thetamax=335;

    figure;
    for length = lengthmin:0.2:lengthmax
        for theta = thetamin:0.5:thetamax
            PSF = fspecial('motion',length,theta);
            res = deconvlucy(I,PSF,100);
            res2 =deconvreg(I,PSF);
            noise_var = 0;
            signal_var = var(double(I(:)));
            estimated_nsr = noise_var/signal_var;
            res1= deconvwnr(I,PSF,estimated_nsr); 
            %res  = medfilt2(rgb2gray(res));
            f = imfilter(res, fspecial('average', [3 3]));
             imshow(f);
        end
    end
```

But, am getting very bad results. May I know what am doing wrong.
Here is a image:

Thanks in advance

[image: original]  [image: deblurred]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deblurring an image with a simulated blur is very different from deblurring an actual camera captured photos.

Motion blur due to camera motion can significantly degrade the quality of an image. Since the path of the camera motion can be arbitrary, deblurring of motion blurred images is a hard problem. There are several methods to deal with this problem such as blind restoration or optical correction using stabilized lenses.

The solution is to use blind deconvolution and the deconvblind command.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvblind.html

Comment: I got somewhat better results with deconvwnr than deconvblind.